# Why is jquery drag not working until I do this

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-draggable

In Php, I have the following line in a foreach loop to create a table with draggable items.
The table is loaded into a div via javascript.

```
echo "<td class='player'><p class='draggable'>$player</p></td>";
```

When I initialize the page, these items are **not** draggable.

To try to figure out the problem, I added a simple div with a draggable paragraph to the html page.

```
<div id='group5' class='person droppable'>
      <p class='draggable'>Drag Me</p>
</div>
```

Dragging this paragraph works fine.  Once I have dragged theis stand alone paragraph (even the tiniest of movement), the items in the table now become draggable.

My guess is that it has something to do with the fact that the table is loaded into a div on the page via javascript while the stand alone paragraph is rendered along with the page's html.

Also, note that the div with the stand alone paragraph is of type **draggable and droppable**.  If I remove droppable, then nothing works.

Thanks -dmd-

Comment: Put your drag initialization inside ```window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => { // Inside this });```

Comment: Thanks Sajeep

I foolishly failed to mention I am using jQuery.

So, I tried

$(window.document ).ready(function() {
   $('p.draggable').draggable();
});

but this did not solve the problem.